# Get completion menu contents: dump to buffer, yank, or return from function?

Tags: vim

One way or another, is it possible to get the contents of a completion pop-up (for a given incomplete string) outside the menu itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. You could either write a macro / function that repeatedly inserts the base text, triggers completion, and then selects the first, second, third, etc. match into the buffer until all have been completed.

Or use a library that emulates the built-in completion. My [CompleteHelper plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914) does that. Example (for the buffer-local `<C-x><C-n>` completion):

```
:let matches = []
:let base = 'ma'
:call CompleteHelper#FindMatches(matches, '\<' . base . '\k\+', {'complete': '.'})
:echo matches
[{'word': 'matches'}, {'word': 'match'}, {'word': 'macro'}]
```